# How to pass dependencies into a controller from a custom middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, middleware

I have a custom middleware from which I want to add a scoped dependency.

```
public class MyMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,
        IOptionsSnapshot<ApiClientHttpSettings> settings,
        IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ICustomer>(new Customer());

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

So that I can get it inside controllers:

```
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
    public ControllerBase(ICustomer customer)
    {

    }    
}
```

But in the middleware `IServiceCollection` cannot be resolved. 
I want to do this because there is a lot of logic to resolve the DI involved.

I can also try to do inside `ConfigureServices` but then I wont get access to `IOptionsSnapshot<SupplyApiClientHttpSettings> settings` I need for every request.

Any pointer to right direction is really appreciated.

Comment: You're kinda working back to front here. This is the code where your middleware executes, the DI configuration should be done in the setup.

Comment: `services.AddScoped<ICustomer>(new Customer());` should be done in `ConfigureServices` within Startup.cs

Comment: @DavidG by setup you mean `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: @p3tch I want to be able to do that but then I need access to updated configuration `IOptionsSnapshot` on every request because the there will be some changes to properties of an instance of `ICustomer` based on the request.

Comment: If `ICustomer` is changing per request, then that object needs the options given to it.

Comment: @DavidG but how do I get updated IOptionsSnapshot inside ConfigureServices for every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple and close. Following is just what I had to do :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICustomer>(provider => {
        var settings = Configuration.GetSection("ApiClientHttpSettings").Get<ApiClientHttpSettings>();
        return new Customer(settings.Name, settings.Age);
    });
}
```

The above ticks all the boxes for me :

1. New instance for each request
2. Able to read updated config at the time of request
3. Create instance according to custom logic

Answer (score 1):

> I can also try to do inside `ConfigureServices`, but then I wont get access to `IOptionsSnapshot<SupplyApiClientHttpSettings>` settings I need for every request.

Here is how you can get access to `IOptionsSnapshot` inside a custom service. The full source is [here in GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-options-snapshot-in-service).

Create your settings class.

```
public class SupplyApiClientHttpSettings
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Add a value for it in configuration (e.g. in `appsettings.json`).

```
{
    "someValue": "Value from appsettings"
}
```

Define your service and inject `IOptionsSnapshot` into it.

```
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly SupplyApiClientHttpSettings settings;

    public CustomerService(IOptionsSnapshot<SupplyApiClientHttpSettings> options)
    {
        this.settings = options.Value;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        return new Customer
        {
            SomeValue = settings.SomeValue
        };
    }
}
```

Wire together your configuration, options, and service in `Startup`.

```
public class Startup
{
    IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Startup()
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<SupplyApiClientHttpSettings>(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<CustomerService>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Inject the service into your controller. Use the service to get the customer with the up to date options snapshot.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService)
    {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Json(customerService.GetCustomer());
    }
}
```

Here is the full source [in GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-options-snapshot-in-service).